# fscanf not reading from file as expected

Tags: c, scanf

I have some code where I am trying to read a clique instance from a file. The first and second lines in the instance file indicate the number of vertices and edges respectively. However my code does not seem to be reading correctly. This is the portion of my code relevant to the question:

```
int num_edges=0;
int num_vertices=0;

char *clique_file = "cliqueinstance";
char *mono_file= "monotone2sat";

FILE* fp_input = fopen(clique_file, "r");
FILE* fp_output = fopen(mono_file, "w");

if (fp_input == 0 )
{
    printf( "Could not open input file\n" );
    return 0;
}

if (fp_output == 0 )
{
    printf( "Could not open output file\n" );
    return 0;
}

fscanf(fp_input, "%d ", &num_vertices);
fscanf(fp_input, "%d ", &num_edges);

printf("\n num of vertices = %d, num of edges = %d ", num_vertices, num_edges); fflush(stdout);
```

My clique instance file looks like this:

```
12
50
<5,1>
etc.
```

I am expecting my code to read 12 as the number of vertices and 50 as the number of edges, however when I print out what it reads, both values are 0.

I am not sure why this is happening, any thoughts?

An update on my question:

My actual program is a series of reductions. Problem P1 is reduced to Problem P2 which is reduced to Problem P3 and so on. I have four of these reductions each represented with a different function. In my main function I call each of these four functions in sequence. In each function I open an input file and write my solution to an output file which then is the input file for the next reduction and so on.

I notice that if I restrict my main function to a single function, then I can read from the file as expected. For this I comment out the calls to the other functions in turn, recompile etc. However if I have more than one function call uncommented, it does not read from the file as expected. Does this have something to do with how fscanf/fgets works? Is the buffer not cleared before its use in the next function call? Any thoughts/ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: fopen returns a pointer, and returns NULL when a failure occurs.  While a 0 can be 'automatically' converted to NULL, it would be much better to actually compare to NULL, not 0  Also, perror() is the proper way to report a problem with a system function, as it include the errno value, the errno message and the enclosed text string.  When exiting a program due to an error, do not return 0 as 0 indicates success, suggest returning EXIT_FAILURE which is defined in stdlib.h

Comment: when calling the fscanf() and family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful

Comment: In general, don't use trailing white space in format strings.  If a user is going to be typing the input, rather than it coming from a file, don't ever use trailing white space in format strings.  The reason is that any white space in a format string consumes any number of white space characters, including newlines, until a non-white space character is entered.  So, to get the `scanf()` to return, the user must type some other character before they're even prompted for what needs to be entered next.  Use `"%d"`.  However, that said, it isn't an immediate cause of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the trailing space just after `%d` in your `fscanf` calls.

```
fscanf(fp_input, "%d", &num_vertices);
fscanf(fp_input, "%d", &num_edges);
```

If you put an space after `%d` in the first `fscanf`, the second one won't read a number unless the trailing space from the first one has been consumed (by reading a space, `\n` or tab).

Comment: Thanks mclead_ideafix, I have already tried that, and it doesn't change what is read, the values read are still 0. Actually, I am guessing that the values are not being read at all.

Comment: What is the value returned by `fscanf`? It should return the number of variables read. In this case, 1.

Comment: Also, check against `NULL` instead of `0`. `NULL` may not be the same as 0.

Comment: Thanks, I checked what fscanf returns. It returns -1 both times. What does that mean?

Comment: Means that wither EOF or an error is happened. If you are using Unix, check the value of errno to see what the actual error is.

Comment: Is your input file really filled with values?

Comment: Yes the input file has values. And I checked the errno, it is 0.

Comment: So it is `EOF` what you have read. What value returns `feof(fp_input)` just after doing the first `fscanf()` ?

Comment: putting a space in a format string means that all white space characters that are encountered at the location in the input stream/file are to be consumed/skipped not that a space has to be at that location in the input

Comment: Note that in a `fscanf()` format, any literal white space character means zero (yes, _zero_) or more white space characters, and newlines count as white space.  It is a good idea to remove the trailing blank in the format string; it is not, however, the cause of the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my question with results from debugging.

Comment: "If you put an space after %d, fscanf will ignore any number not following by a space character" is not correct.  The space _after_ the `"%f"` will not affect if a number was scanned or not.  The `" "` will simply consume trailing white-space - if any.

Comment: So if there is not a space between two numbers in the input file, the " " won't be consumed and the second number won't be read or will be?

Comment: If "there is not a space between two numbers" as in "123-456", your code will read the 2 numbers just fine.  Using format `"%d "` will do the same.  The `" "` format directive never fails.  It reads 0 or more white space.

Comment: Just tried with "123,456". If `fscanf` has a trailing space in the format string, the second number is not read.

Comment: `"123-456"` is 2 numbers.  `"123,456"` is a number, comma, number.  With or without a trailing space in the format, `"456"` will not be read as the comma needs to be consumed first.

Comment: OK, now I get it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I figured out why I wasn't able to read from the file as expected. I was not being careful with closing files at the end of the functions. In my program I have a sequence of steps in which the output file of a step is the input file for the next step and so forth. When I ensure that at the end of each step I close the files with fclose() my program reads from all files as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ran the posted code, using a file that contained

```
12
20
```

using the following function: (modified only to make it a full function)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) 
{
    int num_edges=0;
    int num_vertices=0;

    char *clique_file = "cliqueinstance";
    char *mono_file= "monotone2sat";

    FILE* fp_input = fopen(clique_file, "r");
    FILE* fp_output = fopen(mono_file, "w");

    if (fp_input == 0 )
    {
        printf( "Could not open input file\n" );
        return 0;
    }

    if (fp_output == 0 )
    {
        printf( "Could not open output file\n" );
        return 0;
    }

    fscanf(fp_input, "%d ", &num_vertices);
    fscanf(fp_input, "%d ", &num_edges);

    printf("\n num of vertices = %d, num of edges = %d ", 
        num_vertices, 
        num_edges); 
    fflush(stdout);
    getchar();
    return(0);      
}
```

the result is:

```
num of vertices = 12, num of edges = 20
```

could it be the input file is actually a binary file not a text file

Comment: @MSJ: I agree with this.  Is there any danger that the `cliqueinstance` file is an RTF file, or is Unicode with a BOM at the start, or something else slightly peculiar like that?  Maybe you should do a hex dump of the `cliqueinstance` file, or read it with `fgets()` and then use `sscanf()` to try and get the integers (but that means you can print what you read if you don't convert the integers).  As noted in the main comments, you _must_ check the return value from `fscanf()` to know whether it was successful.

Comment: I have edited my question with an update on my debugging results. Please have a look :)